# Looking for an index of an element in array via SIMD. A fast way

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, simd

I need to find an index/position of an 8-bit value element N in an array ARR via SIMD. It must be a fast fashion.

For now the algorithm is that I'd load 8-bit values of ARR into one SIMD register and a character code of N into other SIMD register.

Then I'd use negation and check which byte is successful with popcnt.

Is there a **faster** way?

The operations may be saturated used if needed.

Comment: Is your array very large (larger than L1, L2, ...)? Does it have exactly one element `N` in it? If not, do you want the index of the first, or of an arbitrary element `N`? How do you currently check which byte is set using `popcnt`? Do you have AVX2/AVX512 or just SSE2?

Answer (score 3):

Which instruction set/architecture are you using? That will somewhat impact the 'correct' answer to this question.

in SSE:

```cpp
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int byteIndex(__m128i ARR, __m128i N)
{
  __m128i cmp = _mm_cmpeq_epi8(ARR, N);
  int mask = _mm_movemask_epi8(cmp);
  return _tzcnt_u32(mask);
}

int main()
{
  __m128i ARR = _mm_setr_epi8(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15);

  // test case that will work
  __m128i N = _mm_set1_epi8(3);
  printf("%d\n", byteIndex(ARR, N));   ///< prints '3'

  // test case that will fail
  __m128i F = _mm_set1_epi8(16);
  printf("%d\n", byteIndex(ARR, F));   ///< prints '32'

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: x86-64. Is your solution faster?

Comment: my question is about a better algorithm. Your solution is what I have described in my question, right?

Comment: `tzcnt` requires BMI, i.e., Haswell or newer. I'm not sure how you, @tajara, (directly) achieve the same with `popcnt` though.

Comment: With C++20, `std::countr_zero` can portably compile to BSF or TZCNT.  If the compiler knows it doesn't have to work for mask==0, it might be able to optimize away extra checks if it's not know that TZCNT is definitely available and it might run as BSF.