# Find index of first occurrence of 16-bit value using AVX/SIMD

Tags: c++, x86, simd, avx, avx2

I'm trying to return the index of the first occurrence of a 16 bit value within 256 bits.
I know how to do this for [8-bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58334014/looking-for-an-index-of-an-element-in-array-via-simd-a-fast-way), using:

```
int _mm256_movemask_epi8 (__m256i a)
```

However, there does not seem to be a 16 bit equivalent intrinsic.
What is the recommended approach?

Comment: 16-bit aligned? Or even crossing 16-bit boundaries?

Comment: @zx485 ignore my previous comment. Yes it can be aligned.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I meant that the vector is `11223344` or can it even be `01122334`. With 8-bit-values this is easy.

Comment: I am searching an std::array containing the 16 bit values. When I find the match, I return the array index.

Comment: You can still use `_mm256_movemask_epi8` and `std::countr_zero` it. Just divide by 2 afterwards.

Comment: How about PCMPEQW?

Comment: Well yes obviously compare first, then movemask. `_mm256_cmpeq_epi16` for people working with intrinsics.

Answer (score 2):

From the comments, it appears the best approach is something like this... (not tested)

```
__m256i veca = _mm256_set1_epi16(a);           // a is 16bit value you're looking for...
__m256i cmp = _mm256_cmpeq_epi16(veca, vecb);  // vecb is the vector you want to search
uint32_t mask = _mm256_movemask_epi8(cmp);     // cmp elements are 0 or 0xffff if no-match or match resp.
uint32_t index = 0;                            // mask is most significant bit of each byte in cmp
if (mask != 0) {
  index = (30 - lzcnt32(mask))/2;              // index is 0-15, 0 on right (higher address).
} else {
  ..no match.
}
```

Comment: `lzcnt` finds the last match.  "Leading" zeros are at the left (high bits), corresponding to higher addresses if `vecb` was loaded from memory.  You want `_tzcnt_u32(mask) >> 1`.  You can use that directly without checking for `mask == 0` if `16` is useful at the no-match result. Otherwise yeah, branch on `mask` before bit-scanning it.  (And if you're using `__builtin_ctz` or other thing that might use `bsf` instead of `tzcnt`, you need to rule out zero.  But I think all AVX2 CPUs have BMI1 / tzcnt.)

Comment: Good point, should've clarified. OP didn't specify whether they meant leftmost or rightmost by 'first occurrence' in their question.

Comment: Surely first occurrence is the one with the lowest index in an array, which is the right-most element in registers.